# CSS and jquery loading

Tags: jquery, html

I am working in a project and experienced a bug (may be a normal condition) that when I tried to load the **home page** of the **website** but the **div** that **I hides** from the  **jquery** is shown to me then got hidden when the **full page** gets **loaded**.

I know this happened because of slow response of the server but I want that this should not be happened at any case.What should I do to make sure that the **div** should remain hidden; by default.

the code I am using right know is pretty straight forward:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#divId').hide();
});
```

this code works fine almost all the time i.e my div remains in hidden mode, but sometimes it gets shown up for a couple of seconds then gets hidden, so is there any technique to make sure that **div** should be in **hidden mode every time (100%)**

Thanks and one more thing because I am new in server side scripting may be I forgot something, so please consider it.
Thanks

Comment: <div id="#divId" style="display:none">...

Comment: hmmm, cant you just but its initial state `display:none`?

Comment: but...remember if you don't use the method you are already using, and your users have js switched off, and you decide you want to show this div with js, your div will never be shown!

Comment: i will use the code with <noscript> that gives the error message...but any way thanks for idea I never thought of the way you thought

Comment: Be aware that your div isn't really gone, so don't put supersecret information in there, hoping that it's really hidden. because it's right there in the source for the curious to find :)

Comment: If it is an error message you are hiding, you are therefore showing it later, in certain (erroneous) circumstances. If you put the code in a <noscript> tag the contents of that tag will always be visible for those with js switched off.  This isn't a good solution for you if your users may have js switched off.

Comment: so how can we handle that situation, can the presence of javascript be known from server side?

Comment: You don't need to know server-side.  Always ensure your pages work without js first.  Then do your nice js stuff over the top.  Wire up your js after the page is loaded; this way you can handle things without js out of the box, but js will take over if it can.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some CSS will do the trick:

```
#divId {
    display: none;
}
```

...and you're done.

Answer (score 5):

why dont you hide it in the html markup

```
style="display:none;"
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not simply hide it with CSS and if you need it then use jQuery to show it.
Either put an in-line style below, or assign it a class/id and give it the below style to the class/id.

```
style="display: none;"
```

You'll never need to hide it on load this way.

Answer (score 1):

Set the div as hidden with stylesheets.

```
<div id="divID" style="display:none">
```